# Can someone please explain me with an example how interface can be used as a method parameter in Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, interface

Clicking button in android:

```
final Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v){}
 saveButton.setTest("Clicked")
}
```

OnClickLister is an interface that is passed inside methodd 
setOnClickListener, I am unsure how this is working?

Comment: That's the object of anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

What you see there is called an [*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (you've chopped a bit off the end, though). It's not an instance of an interface (interfaces can't have instances), although it looks a bit like one. That code creates a class that implements the interface with the given `onClick` method, and then creates an instance of that class to pass into `setOnClickListener`, all in that one `new` expression.

Anonymous classes are meant for situations like this where you just need a one-off instance to pass into a method that accepts an interface. So rather than making you write a separate class definition, several years back (Java 5, I think it was) they added the ability to define a class and create an instance on-the-fly like that.

The code in the `onClick` method also has access to any `final` variables in the method where it's created.

---

The link above is to a Java tutorial on anonymous classes.